# returning multiple values in web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

I am designing a web-service using java and eclipse which returns the user details who are marked as customer in the database

I was successfully able to return details for a single user (as there was only one entry in the dB) with the following code:

```
public class GetData {

public LoginDetails getDetails(){    
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        LoginDetails lds=new LoginDetails();
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from login where usertype='customer'";
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            lds.setUsername(rs.getString(1));
            lds.setPassword(rs.getString(2));
            lds.setUsertype(rs.getString(3));
            lds.setActive(rs.getString(4));

        }
        return lds;
    } 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

What should I do if there are multiple values in dB matching the criteria and I want to display them all. Please advice.

Comment: You can return a [List<LoginDetails>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: I'd just return a `List<LoginDetails>` or `LoginDetails[]`.  One thing though, I don't think it would be wise from a security standpoint to return a user's password.

Comment: @beny23 Right, I was just trying to get a hang of how services work on a preexisting entry in the dB. That's why I was returning the password. My bad :)

Comment: @m0skit0 I tried to do use List as well as Collection but both of them yield the same result- object references.

Comment: Create a new object for each one. You cannot reuse the same one (`lds`) like you do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method signature to `public LoginDetails[] getDetails()`

And extend your while loop as follows:

```
    Collection<LoginDetails> details = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
    while(rs.next()){
        LoginDetails lds=new LoginDetails();
        lds.setUsername(rs.getString(1));
        lds.setPassword(rs.getString(2));
        lds.setUsertype(rs.getString(3));
        lds.setActive(rs.getString(4));
        details.add(lds);

    }
    return details.toArray(new LoginDetails[0]);
```

Comment: I made the required changes and ran the program to get the following warning: 
_The service class "com.tutorial.GetData" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
  The method "getDetails" on the service class "com.tutorial.GetData" uses a data type, "java.util.Collection", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result._

Comment: Ignoring the warning an running the code gives the following output:
**[[Ljava.lang.Object;@19214b1, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1afd9cc]**

Comment: Do I have to make any changes in the wsdl file??

Comment: @NeloAngelo: Ok, Didn't know that. I've changed the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the changes made the warning go away but I am still getting object references.
This is what I got after I made the changes as suggested:
**[com.tutorial.LoginDetails@2507a053, com.tutorial.LoginDetails@349fbf38]**

Comment: @NeloAngelo: That looks fine. Now you can iterate over that Array.

Comment: I am very new to web services and don't have any idea how to iterate the array received in web-serives mode. 
This is what I am getting so far: [Picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/77069305@N04/6918005392/).
Any suggestions on how i should proceed?

Comment: @NeloAngelo: This is a common array. There is nothing special about it because you have received it from a web-service. Your question was about returning multiple values from a web-service. This question is obviously solved now. You should proceed your tutorial now and/or learn the Java basics.

Comment: :) Yeah, the question is resolved. Thanks for the replies man.

Answer (score 0):

Return an collection type suggestively java.util.List , preferably  ArrayList from the method.

Comment: It's a good practice to use the most common type. I'd use `Collection` here. A `List` is ordered a `Collection` isn't. If you use a `List` you should be able to describe in which way it is ordered.